# assembly error initializer magnitude too large for specified size

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I fixed the error, but now can someone suggest a way to make `CountNearMatches` count how many near matches are in the two arrays. I am using the diff variable as the maximum allowed difference.

This is what i have so far:

```
    INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

CountNearMatches PROTO,           ; procedure prototype
    arr1:PTR SDWORD,
    arr2:PTR SDWORD,
    diff3:DWORD

.data

arraySyze DWORD 6
    diff DWORD 3
    index DWORD  0           ;var to use as the first index

    Array1  SDWORD  15, 9, 11, 13, 19, 6
    Array2  SDWORD  14, 5, 3, 12, 1, 4  

    text1 BYTE "************* ASM *****************", 0
    text2 BYTE "*** Counting Nearly Matching Elements ***", 0
    text3 BYTE "the arrays are:...", 0
    text4 BYTE "Nearly Mathces were: ",0

.code
main PROC

    mov edx, offset text1       ;hands the address of the firs char of text1
    call WriteString            ;prints out text1
    call Crlf
    call Crlf

    mov edx, offset text2       ; hands the address of the firs char of text2
    call WriteString            ; prints out text2
    call Crlf
    call Crlf

    mov edx, offset text3       ;hands the address of the firs char of text3
    call WriteString            ;prints out text3
    call Crlf

    mov  esi,OFFSET Array1      ; puts the offset of array in esi
    mov  ecx,arraySyze          ;6
    mov  ebx,TYPE Array1                            
    call DumpMem
    call Crlf

    mov  esi,OFFSET Array2      ; puts the offset of array in esi
    mov  ecx,arraySyze          ;  6
    mov  ebx,TYPE Array1                            
    call DumpMem

    mov eax,0
swapLoop:
    mov ebx, index              ;moves index1 to ebx


    ;here i use the registers to add 8 in to the stack addresses
    INVOKE CountNearMatches, ADDR[Array1 + ebx], ADDR[Array2 + ebx], diff

    add ebx, 4                  ;adding 4 to ebx
    mov index, ebx              ;putting ebx back in to index1

    loop swapLoop

    call Crlf

    mov edx, offset text4       ;hands the address of the firs char of text4
    call WriteString            ;prints out text4



    call WriteInt

    call Crlf
    call Crlf


    call WaitMsg                ; Press any key to contineu...
    exit
main ENDP

; ***************************************
; This is where the magic happnes!
; This function gets its parameters from
; the stack and counts the near mathches
; from the two arrays...
; ***************************************
CountNearMatches PROC USES ebx edx esi edi,
    arr1:PTR SDWORD,                    ;points to the first array
    arr2:PTR SDWORD,                    ;points to the second array
    diff3:DWORD                         ;gets the diff from the stack

;------------------------------------------------------- 

    mov eax,[arr1]
    mov ebx,[arr2]
    mov edx, diff3

    sub eax,ebx
    ret
CountNearMatches ENDP

END main
```

Comment: I'm assuming that it's giving you that error on a specific line???

Comment: What's the complete error message you're getting and what command are you using to assemble this file?

Comment: Thank you for answering.. I am new to assembly...  Im using VS to assemble the file and it gives me the error on the first line of the prototype definition at the bottom of the file --- CountNearMatches PROC USES eax esi edi,

Comment: The error i get is "error A2071: initializer magnitude too large for specified size" on line 71

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. At least `PROTO` declaration of `CountNearMatches` and `PROC` header don't match.

Comment: Yah, I can't reproduce the error. Instead I get there error rkhb got, the  arguments of CountNearMatches are declared in the wrong order.

Comment: Yea, heh ty for pointing that out. I fixed the error, now i just need to actually make it count the near matches. I edited the post with the new code, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.. Now it actually counts all the near matches, not sure if this is the best way but it works. 
here is what i came up with

```
    INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

CountNearMatches PROTO,                                  ; procedure prototype
        arr1:PTR SDWORD,
        arr2:PTR SDWORD,
        diff3:DWORD,
        aSize:DWORD

.data

        arraySize DWORD 6
        diff DWORD 3
        index DWORD  0                                                          ;var to use as the first index
       count DWORD 0
        Array1  SDWORD  15, 9, 11, 13, 19, 6
        Array2  SDWORD  14, 5, 3, 12, 1, 4     

        text1 BYTE "************* ASM *****************", 0
        text2 BYTE "*** Counting Nearly Matching Elements ***", 0
        text3 BYTE "the arrays are:...", 0
        text4 BYTE "Nearly Mathces were: ",0

.code
main PROC

        mov edx, offset text1                                                   ;hands the address of the firs char of text1
        call WriteString                                                                ;prints out text1
        call Crlf
        call Crlf

        mov edx, offset text2                                                   ; hands the address of the firs char of text1
        call WriteString                                                                ; prints out text1
        call Crlf
        call Crlf

        mov edx, offset text3                                                   ;hands the address of the firs char of text1
        call WriteString                                                                ;prints out text1
        call Crlf

        mov  esi,OFFSET Array1                                                  ; puts the offset of array in esi
        mov  ecx,arraySize                                                                      ; count = 6
        mov  ebx,TYPE Array1                                                   
        call DumpMem
        call Crlf

        mov  esi,OFFSET Array2                                                  ; puts the offset of array in esi
        mov  ecx,arraySize                                                                      ; count = 6
        mov  ebx,TYPE Array1                                                   
        call DumpMem

        mov eax,0

        ;here i use the registers to add 8 in to the stack addresses
        INVOKE CountNearMatches, ADDR Array1, ADDR Array2, diff, arraySize

        call Crlf

        mov edx, offset text4                                                   ;hands the address of the firs char of text1
        call WriteString                                                                ;prints out text1

        call WriteInt
        call Crlf
        call Crlf
        call WaitMsg                                                            ; Press any key to contineu...
        exit
main ENDP

; ***************************************
; This is where the magic happnes!
; This function gets its parameters from
; the stack and counts the near mathches
; from the two arrays...
; ***************************************
CountNearMatches PROC USES ebx edx esi edi,
        arr1:PTR SDWORD,                                                        ;points to the first array
        arr2:PTR SDWORD,                                                        ;points to the second array
        diff3:DWORD,                                                                    ;gets the diff from the stack
        aSize:DWORD

;-------------------------------------------------------
        mov edx, 0                                              ;index
        mov ecx, aSize
myLoop:

        mov esi, arr1
        mov edi, arr2
        mov eax, [esi]
        mov ebx, [edi]

        sub eax,ebx
        cmp eax,diff3
        JLE myCount
       add arr1, 4
       add arr2, 4
        loop myLoop
myCount:
    inc count
    add arr1, 4
    add arr2, 4
    loop myLoop
    mov eax, count

    ret
CountNearMatches ENDP

END main
```